# Polygon in Leaflet JS at wrong position

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet, geojson

i´m trying to create a map based on LeafletJS. I need some shapes rendered in the map.

I need - for example "Kreis Wesel" (part of germany) in my map. I downloaded shapefiles from http://www.gadm.org/country and imported them into OpenJump. Fine - they are displayed correctly in the GUI.

When i copy the area to clipboard an format id as JSON (with my texteditor) and parse it width 'L.polygon(var).addTo(map', the polygon is created correctly - but in the Indian Ocean, not in Germany.

Any ideas wheres my fault?

Comment: It certainly has something to do with the projection. What is your base layer? Did you checked that the base layer and the shapes have the same projection/crs/epsg?

Comment: I´m using the default layer (as posten in the quickstart-guide) http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/API-key/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png. Where can i adjust this settings? (Projection e.g.).

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems you can find info in that previous [thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14251/retrieving-tiles-in-epsg4326-format-is-there-a-service-for-that-like-cloudmade)

first two lines: " Is there a service that can provide custom tiles in the EPSG:4326 projection? I've looked at Cloudmade and it would be the ideal solution but their tiles are using Spherical Mercator"

The shapes you downloaded are in lat/lon coordinates epsg:4326 whereas your base layer OpenStreetMap uses Spherical mercator epsg:3857

Change your shape's epsg with your favorite GIS software.

Comment: thank you for your answer! Have you any tip for me how i can do this? I tried it using ogr2ogr with the following command: ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" New.shp ./Germany.shp  -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857  but it ends up with "Unable to open datasource `./Germany.shp' with the following drivers.". But the file is accessible from the directory and i can read / write it (no wrong permissions etc.)

Comment: I think the output should be set before input in your line:`ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:3857 output_vector.shp input_vector.shp`